# Limit of csv file importing in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, sharepoint

I am currently in the process of getting the data from my stakeholder where he has a database from which he is going to extract as a csv file.

From there he is going to upload in shared drive and I am going to pick up the data probably download the data and use that a source locally to import in pandas dataframe.

The approximate size will be 40 million rows, I was wondering if the data can be exported as a single csv file from SQL database and that csv can be used as a source for python dataframe or should it be in chunks as I am not sure what the row limitation of csv file is.

I don't think so ram and processing should be an issue at this time.

Your help is much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: *approximate size will be 40 million rows* what is size do you except in terms of number of bytes? How much RAM you have available? How will you processing said data later?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lazy Method for Reading Big File in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python)

Comment: @Daweo Thanks for the comment, I have updated my question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't connect directly to the database, you might need the .db file. I'm not sure a csv will even be able to handle more than a million or so rows.

Comment: What do you mean by _"I'm not sure a csv will even be able to handle more than a million or so rows."_? (I have worked with csv-files with about half a billion rows.)

Comment: This, I just wanted to know if a single dump of 40 million rows can be considered rather than breaking the files and getting it to shared drive.

Answer (score 0):

> as I am not sure what the row limitation of csv file is.

There is not such limit inherent for CSV format, if you understood CSV as format defined by [RFC4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) which stipulates that CSV file is

```
file = [header CRLF] record *(CRLF record) [CRLF]
```

where `[`...`]` denote optional part, CRLF denote carriagereturn-linefeed (`\r\n`) and `*(`...`)` denote part repeated zero or more times.